# .tmLanguage -- how to include / exclude a variable

Tags: sublimetext2, tmlanguage

I am looking for examples to include / exclude a couple of variables as defined within a `.tmLanguage` file.

**Example 1 -- highlight the whole enchilada, including both variables:**

```
{\code_one*[variable_one]{variable_two}}
```

**Example 2 -- highlight the whole enchilada, less either or both variables:**

```
{\code_two*[variable_three]{variable_four}}
```

Comment: I know you can dream up a better title.

Comment: Thanks -- title modified to be less code-like.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: I've found the best way to learn is to browse through the other .tmLanguage files and see how they do it, whilst keeping a good ref on regexes open for any questions you may have. The whole point of scopes is to highlight specific portions of text, so all you'd have to do is add an exclusionary statement between beginning and end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**include_variable_text** -- e.g., `\hspace*{3.45in}`; `\begin{singlespace*}`; `\end{document}`.

.tmLanguage

```
<!-- BEGIN include_variable_text -->
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>\\makebox\[|\\hspace\*\{|\\begin\{|\\end\{</string>
    <key>beginCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.include_variable_text.begin.latex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>\}|\]</string>
    <key>endCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.include_variable_text.end.latex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>lawlist.include_variable_text.latex</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>$base</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<!-- END -->
```

tm.Theme

```
<!-- BEGIN lawlist.include_variable_text -->
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>Grayed-Out</string>
<key>scope</key>
<string>lawlist.include_variable_text.latex</string>
<key>settings</key>
    <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string>italic</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#E3E3E3</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<!-- END -->
```

---

**exclude_variable_text**

```
{\bf\uline{excluded_variable_text}}
```

.tmLanguage -- This code contains an extra three (3) keys for future use -- e.g., `[anything]`

```
<!-- BEGIN exclude_text -->
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?=\s)(?&lt;=\\[\w@]|\\[\w@]{2}|\\[\w@]{3}|\\[\w@]{4}|\\[\w@]{5}|\\[\w@]{6})\s</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>meta.space-after-command.latex</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>((\{\\bf)(?:\\uline|code_two|code_three))(?:(\[)([^\]]*)(\]))?(\{)</string>
    <key>beginCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.base.latex</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.prefix.latex</string>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.open_square_bracket.latex</string>
        </dict>
        <key>4</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.first_variable.latex</string>
        </dict>
        <key>5</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.close_square_bracket.latex</string>
        </dict>
        <key>6</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist.open_wavy_bracket.latex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>contentName</key>
    <string>lawlist.second_variable.latex</string>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>\}\}</string>
    <key>endCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>lawlist_close_wavy_bracket.latex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>lawlist.whole_enchilada.latex</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>$self</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<!-- END exclude_text -->
```

*.tmTheme

```
<!-- BEGIN strong blue #0000FF -- uline exclude_text -->
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bold / Underline</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>lawlist.base.latex|lawlist.open_square_bracket.latex|lawlist.first_variable.latex|lawlist.close_square_bracket.latex|lawlist.pen_wavy_bracket.latex|lawlist_close_wavy_bracket.latex</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#E3E3E3</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<!-- END -->
```